# upload images in react js public without api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know can we create an upload functionality in react which will upload images to the `PUBLIC` folder in react or anywhere in local system without an API?

I was looking for solution but I could not find anything. one thing that I did find is- I can store image inside an array and display it but I am guessing that is cleared once I refresh the page. If you have any suggestion on this as well please.

Comment: So what you're trying to achieve is "moving" images from your local disk to your local public directory?

Comment: What do you mean by an API? To interact with the file system on a javascript system running on your computer, you will likely need to use node, deno (or other JS runtime) APIs. You need to be clearer on what you want to achieve, and why you need such a functionality.

Comment: yes exactly @Joshua

Comment: read Joshua's comment @cSharp. that is what i want. and i was trying out if it is possible to do such a thing. i know it is  a security risk but still i want to check.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an API if you just want to move one file from your local disk to the react `public` folder. If I've understood correctly your question, you just need to do this:

```
import fs from 'fs';

function moveFileToPublic(filePath, fileName) {
  const source = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
  const destination = fs.createWriteStream(`<public folder>/${fileName}`);
  source.pipe(destination);
}
```

`fs` is a Node.JS module which allows you to interact with the file system in a Node.js environment.

Comment: instead of move can i copy?

Comment: With this code you're already creating a copy of the image, it won't delete it.
If you want to move it, just delete the image at the `filePath`

Comment: seems like `fs` has been stubbed out in `create-react-app`. so cannot use this. do you have any other way?